# vSphere Client time zone problem

Tags: vmware-esxi, vsphere-client

How to adjust time zone in vSphere client which is connected to vCenter server? I know ESXi runs in UTC, but there is also UTC in performance charts, I need local time.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to change the timezone of a VMware ESXi server which you are connected to via vSphere client?

If so, you can change the timezone by opening vSphere client, selecting Inventory and clicking on the hypervisor you want to make changes to. You should then see a tab labelled 'Configuration', click this and then select 'Time Configuration' which within the section labeled 'Software'.

You should then see the current time and if you wish to change it select Properties from the top right and change the time.